# f is a unit in $A[[x]]$ iff $a_0$ is a unit in A. Is the following true?

Tags: commutative-algebra

My question is the following so we can construct the inverse g by constructing the coefficients using induction argument. But, I was wondering if we are given $a_0$ is a unit in A, can we prove that $a_i$ is nilpotent for $i \geq 1$ ? I can't think of a way to do that. Because, if we can do that then we could also prove it using the fact that $a + b$ is a unit for a unit and b nilpotent. We know that in A[x] that f is unit iff $a_0$ is a unit and $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ are nilpotent. If the above isn't true what is the main thing, which is causing this difference between A[x] and A[[x]]. Why isn't the forward direction true that is why if f is a unit, then $a_0$ is a unit and $a_i$ is nilpotent for $i \geq 1$.

Here is my argument for forward direction, to me it doesn't seem to have any problems:

Suppose we have J is arbitrarily prime ideal in k(in your notation) we see that $a_0$ is a unit easily. Consider the ring $R = (A/J)[[x]]$ which is an integral domain together with natural homomorphism $a_0 + a_1x + \ldots \mapsto [a_0] + [a_1]x + \ldots $ as R is integral domain so we must have $[a_i] = 0$ for all $i \geq 1$ Thus, $a_i \in J$, as J is arbitrarily $a_i \in Nil(A)$ for all i >= 1. Can someone point out what gap does my proof have ?

Comment: No, because it isn't true: $1+x+x^2+\cdots$ is certainly a unit in $A[[x]]$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I see. So what is causing here the difference between A[[x]] and A[x], what is the main thing which is causing the problem ?

Comment: There is no problem. The difference between $A[x]$ and $A[[x]]$ is that polynomials have only finitely many terms.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Why doesn't the following argument? If f is a unit. Then Suppose that J is arbitrarily prime ideal of A. Consider $R = (A/J)[[x]]$ together with the natural map $\pi : A[[x]] \rightarrow R$ given by $a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 \ldots \mapsto [a_0] + [a_1]x + \ldots$ . Since R is integral domain $[a_i] = 0$ for all $i \geq 1$, so $a_i \in J$ as J is arbitrarily so $a_i$ is nilpotent for $i \geq 1$.

Comment: How on earth do you get $[a_i]=0$???

Comment: Yeah I see what was the problem the problem is that I assumed that if A is integral domain, then A[[x]] is integral domain (that is true), but the issue is is that I assumed that the units in the integral domain $A[[x]]$ are constants which isn't true.